# Facebook Like on iTunes App Store

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-like

Is there a way to programmatically activate a Facebook Like on the iTunes App Store for an app using objective-c?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid but I think you may have to use it as web view from the generated code of facebook developer: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/